# Angular js Append Elements in header on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have [this code example on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ys4IvflmQwUEjnVlWaXo?p=preview)!

```
<html ng-app='sampleApp'>
<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" 
src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"> 
</script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" 
src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular-route.js" data-semver="1.4.9"> 
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="headerController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="HeaderController">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sample App</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="{ active: isActive('/')}"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="{ active: isActive('/about')}"><a href="#/about">About</a> 
</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>
<ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using for my web application Angular JS where the header is always available on the top of the page to navigate to other html pages and load its content underneath this header.

Now my Problem is that I want to add a new element to this header with a button click, in my example it is the page home.html in plnkr.

I want to append the element prev to the header (before home.html) to enable to navigate to it, and to navigate directly to the page with on click.

So at the same time it should append prev before home and navigate to the page(load the content of prev.html underneath the header).

Is it possible?

I am very thankful for every tip or solution! Cheers

Comment: Why not just use `ng-repeat` for your links and add another object to the array?

Comment: Also since you are using `ui-router` can use `ui-sref` and `ui-sref-active` for `href` and `class`